# How to enumerate values of custom user property in Outlook C#

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created custom user property in Outlook called "Ownership". When someone from the team claim ownership of an email, person's name is saved as its value.

My question, is there any way to enumerate all the values of this custom property into combo box.

In simple words, get a list of all team members names (whoever has claimed ownership of an email in inbox folder).

I want to do something like this.

```
Outlook.UserDefinedProperties userDefinedProperties = null;
Outlook.UserDefinedProperty userDefinedProperty = null;

Outlook.MAPIFolder currentFolder = application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
mailUserProperties = currentFolder.UserDefinedProperties;
mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties["Ownership"];

// Filling up the combo box
PersonCombo.Items.Add(userDefinedProperty.Value);
```

I want to use current folder because folder will have all the values while an email can only have one value of the custom property.

If this is not possible, is there any other way to get it done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you already know all the people from the team, why don't you populate the combo box with their names?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev that's because my add-in will be used by different departments and I don't want to maintain the list of the people if someone new joins the department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a single query that will return all unique values of a particular named property. The best you can do is search for all items where the property exists (not null), and then build a list of unique values.

I do not think, however, this is a good of storing possible values - it really must be a single source, such as a particular GAL distribution list, or a hidden (associated) message in the folder that stores all possible values in a single property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input.
At the end, I ended up creating GAL distribution list as Dmitry suggested and used it for my purpose.